# How can I create a new object with a pre selected foreign key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Car and Appointment model. The idea is to search for the car and create a new appointment with the car_id as a pre inputted foreign key (or association) in the appointment model.

Can I do this through the Path? I would like to add `new_appointment_path(@car)` on the **show** path for **car**, but this doesn't work and I'm not sure if a similar thing is possible?

There's not really any code to post, but needless to say,

```
Appointment 
belongs_to :car
```

and

```
Car 
has_many :appointments
```

Thanks

To elaborate (As I realise it's a bit unclear) I would like to be on the route 'cars/1' and click 'create appointment' to bring up the appointment form with the cars association already added.

so new_appointment_path with the car object that I'm currently on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided you have an instance `@car` of the `Car` model, you could

```
link_to 'New Appointment', new_appointment_path(car_id: @car.id)
```

And then in the controller

```
class AppointmentsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @car = params[:car_id]
    # and then the rest of the new action code
  end
end
```

Comment: Ok, So would this allow me to do cars/1/appointments/new to create a new form with the car association already inputted?

Comment: That route would go toward creating a new `Appointment` instance for a `Car` instance with `id = 1`.

Comment: Ok, the physical routes aren't necessary for me.. are they required? (I have updated my question with a brief elaboration)

Comment: Well, that's the idea behind nested resources. If you just wanted to have it work in the way you described, you could just do `new_appointment_path(car_id: @car.id)`, and then in your controller you could do something like `def new; @car = params[:car_id]; end`

Comment: That's perfect! thank you. feel free to add it as an answer and I will accept.